# Angularfire getRedirectResult returns null when use AngularFireAuthGuard

Tags: angular, firebase, oauth-2.0, angularfire2

I'm using *AngularFireAuthGuard* to control access to different parts of the application. I was logging into the application through a Google account and Firebase and had no problems until I decided to add two more providers (Facebook and Twitter). When logging in with one of the new providers and checking the *auth/account-exists-with-different-credential* error to link the accounts, I found that *GetRedirectResult* returns null, when it should return the error. I have found that removing the redirects from *AngularFireAuthGuard* makes everything work correctly.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const redirectUnauthorizedToLogin = (next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
    return redirectUnauthorizedTo(`/sign-in?redirectTo=${state.url}`);
};

const redirectLoggedInToDashboard = (next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
  console.log(next.params);

  let returnUrl = next.queryParams['redirectTo'];

  if (returnUrl !== undefined) {
    return redirectLoggedInTo(returnUrl);
  } else {
    return redirectLoggedInTo('/');
  }
};
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent, canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: redirectLoggedInToDashboard } },
  { path: 'home',
    component: AppLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
    ],
    canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard],
    data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLogin }
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home' }
];
```

The following code is the login page. In it I collect the results of the redirect to check if it was successful or returned an error. This is where I run into the problem that I get null when there should be an error.

**sign-in.component.ts**

```
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
    private auth: Auth,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private authService: AuthService) {

     }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const result = getRedirectResult(this.auth)
      .then(user => {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const code = error.code;
        const credential = error.credential;

        if (code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
          this.afAuth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(credential.email).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
          });
        }

        console.log(credential);
      });
  }

  loginWithGoogle() {
    this.authService.loginGoogle(this.auth);
  }

  loginWithFacebook() {
    this.authService.loginFacebook(this.auth);
  }

  loginWithTwitter() {
    this.authService.loginTwitter(this.auth);
  }
```

The Auth Service:

**auth-service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {

  currentUser: UserInfo | null = null;
  private authStateSub = new BehaviorSubject<UserInfo | null>(null);
  currentAuthStatus = this.authStateSub.asObservable();

  constructor(private auth: Auth,
    public angularFire: AngularFireAuth)
  {
    this.authStatusListener();
  }

  authStatusListener() {
    this.angularFire.onAuthStateChanged((credential) => {
      console.info(JSON.stringify(credential));
      if (credential) {
        this.currentUser = credential;
        this.authStateSub.next(this.currentUser);
      } else {
        this.authStateSub.next(null);
      }
    })
  }

  async loginGoogle(auth: Auth): Promise<UserCredential> {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
    provider.setCustomParameters({
      prompt: 'select_account'
    });

      return await signInWithRedirect(auth,provider);
  }

  async loginFacebook(auth: Auth): Promise<UserCredential> {
    const provider = new FacebookAuthProvider();

    provider.addScope('email');
    provider.setCustomParameters({
      prompt: 'select_account'
    });

    return await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  }

  async loginTwitter(auth: Auth): Promise<UserCredential> {
    const provider = new TwitterAuthProvider();

    return await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  }

  logout() {
    return this.auth.signOut()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('logout');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

I think that when I make the redirections I lose the Auth reference and that's why what I get is not the expected value. I have read in the Firebase documentation that it is necessary to save the credentials in session variables between redirections, but I don't see where I can do that, because at all times, once I come back from the providers account selection page, every value is null.

Thanks in advance